# overwritten values in loops: Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, loops

The code below , when I execute it, ub,u, p, q arrays are shown like 101 times since ii=101 in the code. What I mean is the loop does not work. Could you look at it please

```
ii=101;
dt=0.0001;
t = 0:dt:1000;
dx=0.01; %step size
pi=4.*atan(1);
fik=0.4;
H1=0.5;
H1D=0;
A=0;
AD=0.1;
ADinit=AD;
c1b=0.5;
c2b=1-c1b;
dc=0.001;

for i=1:ii;
x=(i-1)*dx;
        fikness=fik*sin(pi*x);
        ub1(i)=(c1b-H1D*(x-0.5)+AD/2*(x-0.5)^2)/(H1-0.5*fikness-A*(x-0.5))
        ub2(i)=(c2b+H1D*(x-0.5)-AD/2*(x-0.5)^2)/(1-H1+0.5*fikness+A*(x-0.5))

end

c1=c1b+dc;
c2=1-c1;
for i=1:ii;
    x=(i-1)*dx;
        fikness=fik*sin(pi*x);
        u1(i)=(c1-H1D*(x-0.5)+AD/2*(x-0.5)^2)./(H1-0.5*fikness-A*(x-0.5))
        u2(i)=(c2+H1D*(x-0.5)-AD/2*(x-0.5)^2)./(1-H1+0.5*fikness+A*(x-0.5)) 
end

p1(1)=0.5*(1-u1(1)^2);
q1(1)=0;
p2(1)=0.5*(1-u2(1)^2);
q2(1)=0;

for i=2:ii

q1(i)=q1(i-1)-dx*(u1(i-1)-ub1(i-1))/dt
p1(i)=0.5*(1-u1(i)^2)+q1(i)
end 

for i=2:ii;
q2(i)=q2(i-1)-dx*(u2(i-1)-ub2(i-1))/dt
p2(i)=0.5*(1-u2(i)^2)+q2(i)
end
```

ub1,ub2,u1,u2,p1,p2,q1,q2 =1*101, all of them have one row 101 column How can I access the whole arrays of ub1,ub2,u1,u2,p1,p2,q1,q2 ??

Comment: Do you mean like "u(:)"?

Comment: I do not know what it means. In for loop i from 1 to 101. I maust have u(1) u(2) ..... u(101) I mean 1 row 101 column.But it computes 101 times 101 values for u and for others as well.

Comment: Try transposing it: `u1 = u1';` (note the single quote).

Comment: it would be again 101*101 .I need 1*101 for each value such as u1 u2 ub1 ub2 ...

Answer (score 0):

the command prompt will show all calculations which are not followed by a semicolon. even if you are assigning one element of an array, it will show the whole array.

`p(1)=1`
this shows all of p, not just the first element. put semicolon at the end of each assignment statement or calculation like

`p2(i)=0.5*(1-u2(i)^2)+q2(i);`

then at the end of the code write

```
u1
u2
```

this should show the final vectors

Comment: they are I mean the arrays are not consisting of certain integers that is why I cannot use semicolon to separate them. What I see is 101 times the same u1, or so.